# 10 images bouncing javascript. Can not use clearRect

Tags: javascript

Hello i am making this code where there are 10 images on the canvas and are supposed to start bouncing across the canvas. The problem is i do not know how to use clearRect in this case. i tried it and i can't make it work. Also it seems that the images start going slower when the time passes.

```js
<html>
<head><title>Pregunta clases</title></head>
<body>
<canvas id="ventana" width="600" height="600" style="border:2px solid #000000;"></canvas>

<script>

var canvas=document.getElementById("ventana");
var context=canvas.getContext("2d");


var cuadrados=10;
var y = [];


var x = [];
var Cuadrado1 = new Image();
Cuadrado1.src = 'cuadrado1.jpg';

for(i=0;i<cuadrados;i++) {
 x.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 570)); 
}


for(i=0;i<cuadrados;i++) {
 y.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 570));
}
 
var velocidad=5;
var direccion=1;
var contador=0;
var contador2=0;



 var aeio= setInterval(function ab(){
 
 for(k=0;k<cuadrados;k++) {


context.drawImage(Cuadrado1, x[k], y[k], 30, 30);

if(y[k]>=600){
 direccion= -1;
 
}else if(y[k]<=0){
    direccion= 1;
    
}
 y[k] = y[k]+ velocidad*direccion;
}


}, 1);



//contador
for(j=0;j<cuadrados;j++){
if(x[j]>300){
 contador= contador + 1;
} else if(x[j]<=300){
 contador2= contador2 + 1;
}
}
context.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
</script>

<div id="posiciones cuadrados">
<script>
document.write("Hay "+contador+" cuadrados en el lado derecho");
document.write("<br>Hay "+contador2+" cuadrados en el lado izquierdo");
document.write("<br>El primer cuadrado se encuentra en "+x[0]+" ,  "+y[0]);
document.write("<br>El segundo cuadrado se encuentra en "+x[1]+" ,  "+y[1]);
document.write("<br>El tercer cuadrado se encuentra en "+x[2]+" ,  "+y[2]);
document.write("<br>El cuarto cuadrado se encuentra en "+x[3]+" ,  "+y[3]);
document.write("<br>El quinto cuadrado se encuentra en "+x[4]+" ,  "+y[4]);
document.write("<br>El sexto cuadrado se encuentra en "+x[5]+" ,  "+y[5]);
document.write("<br>El septimo cuadrado se encuentra en "+x[6]+" ,  "+y[6]);
document.write("<br>El octavo cuadrado se encuentra en "+x[7]+" ,  "+y[7]);
document.write("<br>El noveno cuadrado se encuentra en "+x[8]+" ,  "+y[8]);
document.write("<br>El decimo cuadrado se encuentra en "+x[9]+" ,  "+y[9]);



</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure you property included the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the whole canvas in each frame.

```
var aeio = setInterval(function ab() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);

    for (k = 0; k < cuadrados; k++) {
        context.drawImage(Cuadrado1, x[k], y[k], 30, 30);
        if (y[k] >= 600) {
            direccion = -1;
        } else if (y[k] <= 0) {
            direccion = 1;
        }
        y[k] = y[k] + velocidad * direccion;
    }
}, 1);
```